# Preserving new line characters while storing shell command result into a variable

Tags: bash, shell, echo

when I am doing this

```
echo -e "hello\nworld"
```

the result is like this

```
hello
world
```

But, Here I am trying to store the shell command result into a variable and I am trying to reuse that variable, like this

```
output=$(echo -e "hello\nworld")
echo $output
```

then the result is like this

```
hello world
```

But, I am expecting a result like the first one, printed in two lines. How to achieve this?

Comment: *word-splitting* can be your friend or enemy. Try this `(IFS=; output=$(echo -e "hello\nworld"); echo $output)` -- include the `(..)` so it runs in a subshell to prevent changing `IFS` (*Internal Field Separator*) for your current shell. Of course quoting `echo "$output"` will also do.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Why would you ever do that when you can just quote `$()`.